# Elseif is not working in Excel Makro (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

i have a little problem in my excel macro.

Description of the Problem:

I want to create a Macro, which hide / unhide special Sheets, if one answer is a Dropdown Menu used.

Dropdown Menu:

Australian

Austria

Germany

And if one of them choosen e.g, Germany --> the Sheet with Germany should unhide and the sheet with australian and austria should hide.

I try to use the ElseIf Command:

```
Sub Choose_Country()

If (c2 = "Germany") Then

Sheet8.Visible = True
Sheet9.Visible = False
Sheet10.Visible = False

ElseIf (C2 = Australia) Then

Sheet8.Visible = False
Sheet9.Visible = True
Sheet10.Visible = False

ElseIf (C2 = Austria) Then

Sheet8.Visible = False
Sheet9.Visible = False
Sheet10.Visible = True

End if 
End sub
```

The Error is, that it doesn't matter what i choose every time the germany sheet is visible and the others not..

Any Ideas what my mistake is ?

Regards

Comment: Why not use `Select Case c2` instead of all these `If` clauses? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot quite a few ""
As @Raph said, select case is way cleaner to look at.

Tip: Always use Option Explicit, you would have spotted this one!!!

Tip 2 : you may use lcase(   ) to compare case insensitive

```
Sub Choose_Country()
c2 = something I dare hope :D
select case c2
case "Germany"

Sheet8.Visible = True
Sheet9.Visible = False
Sheet10.Visible = False

case "Australia"

Sheet8.Visible = False
Sheet9.Visible = True
Sheet10.Visible = False

case "Austria"

Sheet8.Visible = False
Sheet9.Visible = False
Sheet10.Visible = True
case else
      msgbox "unknown country"
End select
End sub
```

Comment: Whilst this isnt an answer I do agree, but I think it would be good if you provided an example of a way to do select case

Comment: @Mr.Burns it is a dumb answer but I'm pretty sure the problems is with the "" . I'll add this :)

Comment: There is many problems with the code, the "" is just one of the (Though I may be being picky) but for the sake of helping someone understand hw to improve an example of the select case would likely improve alot (My first use of select case was a mess)

Comment: @Pierre : Does `Case "string"` works in VBA too? I always type `Case Is = "string"`...

Comment: Edited. @R3uK : Yes it does the same. Shorter therefore cleaner to look at :-)

Comment: @Pierre : Thx! So I've wasted so much time for nothing!^^

Comment: @R3uK : np that's what this place is for. :-)  I just learned the difference between value and value2 here.